# create current_something helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use devise plugin and there is `current_user` helper. My users can have many profiles in application so User have `has_many :profiles` and always one of them is active.

How, and where can I create helper `current_profile`?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the helper in `ApplicationController`, which will make it available to all controllers and views that inherit from it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  protect_from_forgery  
  helper_method :current_profile  

 private  
  def current_profile  
    # get current_profile based on current_user here
  end  
end
```

Now you can use `current_profile` in any views/controllers.

Answer (score 1):

In the `User` class I would add a method

```
class User
  has_many :profiles

  def current_profile
    @current_profile ||= profiles.where('current = ?', true).first
  end
end
```

and then inside your controller/helpers you could just write:

```
current_user.current_profile
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as how**, is really just a matter of figuring out which profile is active (I'm assuming that a user can ONLY have 1 active profile in a given session - that will make it easier). So, what you do is use your session info to find out the current user, then find the active profile, and bingo - you're done.

**As far as where**, that's really a question of scope. If you want to have the helper method available to any view, simply declare it in the application controller, and you should be good.